# Different role for two users in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the condition where all users are created by admin and user name and password given to them. When the created user login than pro user can create post, upload files, edit their profile but the free user only can create and edit their profile no upload the files and no post. Also the pro users post must be approved by admin than only visible to public. What is the role suited for free and pro users for this condition ?

Comment: Try to avoid asking for the "best" role. Better ask for a suitable one.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with editor and subscriber role for it

Comment: ok thanks for your suggestion i solved that by creating new users as my requirement using add_role and works fine.